# Definições de unget() e putback()

Tags: c++, c++11

Procurei algumas definições e até agora o que eu tenho conhecimento é que o `unget()` retorna obrigatoriamente a ultima caractere e o `putback()` dá para retornar outras que não sejam a ultima.

Mas a minha dúvida seria no funcionamento. Eu gostaria de saber os usos práticos, por que é usado, ele retorna para onde?

Fiz um teste onde dei entrada em um char, dei o `unget()` e depois usei uma entrada em outra variável e notei que ela se auto-preencheu com o carácter retornado e consegui ter uma ideia bem superficial.

Gostaria que me explicassem essa mecânica envolvendo o buffer, o clean depois de um erro e as questões no segundo parágrafo.

Comment: Um uso comum é em analisadores léxicos - programas que convertem uma sequência de caracteres em uma sequência de símbolos (*tokens*). Eles são usados em compiladores e outros *parsers* de arquivos em formatos baseados em texto (XML, JSON, etc.). A operação de devolver um caractere para ler ele de novo permite usar a entrada como uma estrutura de pilha (`get` = `pop`, `unget` = `push`) ao invés de uma simples sequência, simplificando alguns algoritmos léxicos.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo também achei muito confuso esses dois membros, mas quando os entendi, vi o quão poderosos eles são!
Vamos la, o unget() retorna apenas um caractere para o buffer de entrada cin, ou seja se você usar cin >> variável, a variável vai adquirir o ultimo caractere valido, não me recordo se espaço conta acho que para antes do espaço!

Ja o putback() é mágico, uma verdadeira perfeição para filtrar dados, exemplo de uso em uma data, você quer retirar o dia, mes, ano e armazenar em variaveis, você poderia usar este exemplo.

```
int main(){
char ch;
int dia;
int mes;
int ano;

int contador_barras = 0;
while (cin){
    cin >> ch;
    switch (ch){
    case '\\': case '/':
        contador_barras++;
        break;
    case '0': case '1': case '2':case '3': case '4': case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        if (contador_barras == 0)
        {
            cin.putback(ch);
            cin >> dia;
        }
        if (contador_barras == 1)
        {
            cin.putback(ch);
            cin >> mes;
        }else if (contador_barras == 2)
        {
            cin.putback(ch);
            cin >> ano;
        }
        break;
    case ';':
        cout << dia << " - " << mes << " - " << ano << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

após o uso de cin.putback, posso usar um cin >> ano que ele vai ler todos os números antes da barra, funciona com strings e espaços, string e números...

faça teste melhor maneira de tirar suas duvidas!